# How can I call model method from template by passing parameters

Tags: python, django

Whenever I need a full collection of info I can pass through context data to template but when I need to collect data from a loop running in template by passing any id to other table and make query to get specific info of that each individual id how to do it in Django. In php we can run query from template by passing parameters that thing how to do it in django.

Example: in template (for product in products)

Now I want to collect stock details of each individual product of this loop by querying store table.

This is one problem I want to solve.

(endfor )

Another is :

In a routine making process I want to show teacher's name and subject name. In each time slot. Such as.

```
day = 2
 (for time in times )
```

Now from routine table I want to get teacher name and subject name for day 2 and time could be 9.00-9.45 or 9.45-10.15
View sould be like this
Jhon/english

(endfor )
Routine model is: 
Routine table   teacher_id = models.IntegerField() ,subject_id = models.IntegerField(), time_id=models.IntegerField(),day_id = models.IntegerField()

It's easy in php but how to do it with Django I'm in need of help.

Comment: The question isn't very clear. But Django's template language is - by deliberate design - very restricted compared to many others, so you can't call a function and pass arguments to it from a template. You're supposed to perform any relatively complex "business logic" in the view function instead. If you give more detail on what you're trying to do, with some code if possible, then we might be able to show you how to do it.

Comment: Apologies, I only just came back and saw your edits - if you'd have left a comment to say you'd edited I'd have seen it sooner. What you're describing is quite easy, but you have to set up your models correctly. Your `teacher_id` in the `Routine` model shouldn't be an `IntegerField`, it should be a `ForeignKey` to the teacher table. Then, if you rename it `teacher` (as would be the convention), you can access `routine.teacher.name` (or the equvalent with whatever field names you have) to get the name, all from in the template. And similarly for the other cases.